# If one must break fast to drink, should they eat as well?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

A Muslim has a permanent medical condition that causes severe health problems if they don't drink water during the day. However, they have no medical need for food.

During the fast in Ramadan, should they abstain from food, sex, and other prohibited activities besides drinking?

Is there any difference (e.g. for fidyah) between their case and a sick person who needs food?

Comment: Welcome to Islam.SE! Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [how to ask a question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), and take a [tour](https://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) in the [help center](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: if they have a valid shariah reason to not fast, then they can resume as normal.